# Custom animation of views while entering fullscreen mode in os x application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

Is there any way to implement an animation (frame changing) for views at the same time, when app is going to full screen?

Briefly:

I have an app with 1 window, which contains 3 views on it.For some reasons these views can't be autoresized.(springs struts can't be applied)

So,when app goes to fullScreen - the window becomes big, but views still remain small, and only in

```
-(void)windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
```

i can adjust their frames, so there is a noticeable lag.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Custom Full-Screen Presentation Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008202-CH1-SW51) section of the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol documentation. In particular, I think you'll want `–customWindowsToEnterFullScreenForWindow:` and `-window:startCustomAnimationToEnterFullScreenWithDuration:`.